# can I build an electron app for Mac on a linux system?

Tags: linux, macos, docker, virtualbox, electron

I read some docs, and probably the direct answer is "not, that's not possible!".
But I was wondering if there is a chance to reach the goal with some kind of system like VirtualBox, Docker, ....

I'd like to understand if it makes sense trying those ways before to waste too much time. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

[Building macOS packages on Linux is possible with some caveats:](https://www.electron.build/multi-platform-build)

- macOS apps can only be code signed on macOS.
- npm packages using native modules must offer prebuilt binaries for the target platform.

It's probably best to just avoid native modules where possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Mac on Virtual Box so probably you can do that...
Something like this https://techsviewer.com/install-macos-sierra-vmware-windows/ 
For linux, things are similar. Just download VMDK (Virtual Machine Disk) and use it.
At Debian after you create machine you need few settings commands and that is all...
Performance are ok

Comment: Just know that unless you do this on Apple hardware (which defeats the purpose) than you are breaking the macOS EULA by doing this.

Comment: can I do this? I dont have macOS and cant afford it.

Comment: Yes you can, it will be pain and far from perfect (in terms of stability) but it is possible and looks cool :)